# How do you set up ports when you don't use the new "frames"

Tags: catan

I received a new [Catan Board](http://mycatanboards.com/products/official-plastic-catan-board-5-to-6-player) and we attempted to setup the 5-6 player game.  I realized that I had forgotten how to setup the ports, but since I had also got a new copy of the game, it didn't say how to set them up without the new "frames" that are included.

How do you set up the ports in Settlers of Catan if you don't use the frames?

Answer (score 5):

In the 3-4 player game you start with placing a port on the hexside at the end of a long (5 piece) row.  You then place a port every other space around the map.  Each port is placed oriented towards the hexside of the longest row it is next to.

In the 5-6 player game it is more complicated.  Here is a snapshot of the rules so you can see how to place the ports correctly:

[image: 5-6 player port setup]